# cannot invoke initialiser for type "NSError" with (domain, code, userInfo) in AppDelegate coredata, Swift 2

Tags: core-data, swift2, appdelegate, nserror

I also just update to Xcode 7 and there I met this problem in my AppDelegate.swift

```
 lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Inclinometer.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."


    let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: mOptions)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1

        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

It shows in this line

```
error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
```

that cannot invoke initialiser for type "NSError" with an argument list of type (domain, code, userInfo). How should one change it to make it run in Xcode 7?

Answer (score 0):

The `NSError` initializer expects an argument of type `[String: AnyObject]` for the `userInfo`. You have to write it like this:

```
let dict : [String: AnyObject] = [
  NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to initialize the application's saved data",
  NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : failureReason
  NSUnderlyingErrorKey : error
]
```

Also, I think you do not have a need to create an additional error variable (defined where?) and overwrite it.

Comment: Hi, It showed "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" now just by this "let dict:". Do you mean that I don't need to define "error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)"?

Comment: Besides, I think it does expect not only string. See "NSError(domain: <String>, code: <Int>, userInfo: <[NSObject : AnyObject]?>))"

Comment: Doesn't work in Xcode 7.0 (Which the question asked about). I get "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you've got to be extra specific with what you are putting in a Dictionary, in XCode 7.0 this works for me

```
let dict : [String: AnyObject] = [
        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to initialize the application’s saved data",
        NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: String(failureReason),
        NSUnderlyingErrorKey: String(error),
    ]
error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
```